# Array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I believe that what I'm trying to do is declare several arrays within an array.
In a text document, I have the following:

```
"一","いち","one"
"二","に","two"
"三","さん","three"
"四","し・よん","four"
"五","ご","five"
```

Which I want to automatically place into an array with the items assigned as groups of 3, so for instance set_one[0][1] would be "いち", set_one[3][2] would be "four", so on.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to even read the values line by line from the plain text document, let alone try to automatically assign them into arrays.. so I tried manually. I have:

```
var set_one = new Array(new Array("一", "いち","one"), new Array("二", "に","two", new Array("三", "さん","three", new Array("四", "よん・し","four", new Array("五", "ご","five");
```

Which, when document.write(set_one[3][2]); is called, nothing happens what-so-ever.. I even tried a for loop to see if anything exists in the (set_one) array at all, though as far as I can tell, nothing does.

It's difficult working on this windows machine to say the least, as I have no debugging tools available, and it doesn't have an active Internet connection! What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this? Is it even possible to read the values into an array automatically line-by-line, then assign the values to individual arrays based on the comma values?

Comment: At what stage of your JavaScript execution are you calling `document.write()`? During the parse and execute phase?

Comment: Probably nothing happens due to the fact that you have several unclosed parentheses...?!

Comment: My entire script so far is just that variable definition and then the document.write() function.

Comment: Also, use `['foo', 'bar']` instead of `new Array('foo', 'bar')` for your sanity.

Comment: +1 @deceze . Note for example that `new Array(10)` is very different from `[10]` while `new Array(10, 2)` is the same as `[10, 2]`...

Comment: @deceze I shall try your suggestion now, I have a feeling my textbook may be a little outdated. I'm sorry about the parentheses too, I am a complete fail when it comes to simple things such as copy/paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not creating the array correctly. For example, when you have:

```
new Array("二", "に","two", new Array("三", "さん","three"))
```

You are actually creating a single-element array, in which the *3rd* position is *itself* another array. Either use:

```
new Array (new Array("二", "に","two"), new Array("三", "さん","three"))
```

Or the much simpler, and less confusing way of creating arrays in JavaScript:

```
var set_one = [ 
  [ "一","いち","one" ],
  [ "二","に","two" ],
  [ "三","さん","three" ],
  [ "四","し・よん","four" ],
  [ "五","ご","five" ] 
];
set_one[0][1]; // いち
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var set_one = [
["一","いち","one"], 
["二","に","two"], 
["三","さん","three"], 
["四","し・よん","four"], 
["五","ご","five"]
];
```